# Don't show a particular user account on the login page

Tags: user-account

I created a new user account that I needed for a specific program, but it doesn't represent a regular user. How do I prevent this user from showing up as an option on the login page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both in 10.7 and 10.6 you will need their shortname then just run this command in Terminal.app

```
$ sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow HiddenUsersList -array-add user1 user2 user3
```

To remove them from the hidden user list:

```
$ sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow HiddenUsersList
```